# Nginx Reverse Proxy returning 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-404, arch-linux

I'm using Nginx as a caching proxy for ArchLinux mirrors (to speed up internal server builds).  It correctly reverse proxies four sites, but returns mysterious 404s on the fifth.

/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:

```
user http;
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/access_log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/error_log  debug;

    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay    off;

    keepalive_timeout  30;

    gzip  on;

    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_cache_path /srv/http/nginx/proxy levels=1 keys_zone=one:256m inactive=5d max_size=512m;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 100 8k;
    proxy_connect_timeout      60;
    proxy_send_timeout         60;
    proxy_read_timeout         60;

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_cache             one;
    proxy_cache_key         $request_uri;
    proxy_cache_valid       200 301 302 30m;
    proxy_cache_valid       404 1m;
    proxy_cache_valid       any 15m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating;

    include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*.conf;

}
```

/etc/nginx/vhosts/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mirror.example.com;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /one {
        proxy_pass http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/linux/distributions/archlinux/;
    }

    location /two {
        proxy_pass http://mirrors.xmission.com/archlinux/;
    }

    location /three {
        proxy_pass http://mirror.rit.edu/archlinux/;
    }

    location /four {
        proxy_pass http://lug.mtu.edu/archlinux/ftpfull/;
    }

    location /five {
        proxy_pass http://repo.archlinux.fr/i686/;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

`/one`, `/two`, `/three`, and `/four` work flawlessly, but `/five` always gives a 404.  The site is accessible from the server (verified by copy-pasting into lynx).  I cannot figure out why.  The only thing in the log file is:

```
Nov 12 09:49:54 mirror NginxMirror: 10.0.1.91 - - [12/Nov/2010:09:49:54 -0500] "GET /five HTTP/1.1" 404 257 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.12" "-"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this IP - 10.0.1.91 ???

Have you checked your dns? have you checked your not caching something bad in Nginx?

i have just added this to my Nginx configuration

```
location /five {
    proxy_pass http://repo.archlinux.fr/i686/;
}
```

And it works :/

P.S take this out

## proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

Comment: Already tried clearing the cache: doesn't work.  DNS resolves because it works when I SSH into mirror and `lynx http://repo.archlinux.fr/i686/`The IP in the log is the computer making the request on the mirror (my desktop).  It's just the first example in the logs I found.

Comment: Remove the other locations for testing purposes..
Maybe its a bug.. Your config clearly works for the others, its strange it doesnt work for this one

Comment: Just tried that.  Commented out all locations except `/five`.  Didn't work.